# Inconsistent results loading association via has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When loading associations using `has_many :through` as shown in the code sample below (self contained/executing), leads to unexpected records to load, as shown in the assertion failure. I'm not sure whats missing to make the test pass.

```
unless File.exist?('Gemfile')
  File.write('Gemfile', <<-GEMFILE)
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
    gem 'sqlite3'
  GEMFILE

  system 'bundle'
end

require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup(:default)

require 'active_record'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'logger'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:')
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table "blogs" do |t|
    t.integer :subject_id
    t.integer :author_id
  end

  create_table "subjects"
  create_table "authors"
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs, dependent: :destroy
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :all_blogs_with_subject, through: :subjects, source: :blogs
  has_many :blogs
  has_many :subjects, through: :blogs
end

class HasManyThroughLoadTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_loading_associations_via_has_many_through
    author_one = Author.create!
    author_two = Author.create!
    Subject.create!(blogs: [Blog.new(author: author_one), Blog.new(author: author_one)])
    Subject.create!(blogs: [Blog.new(author: author_one), Blog.new(author: author_two)])

    # Expected 1, Actual 2 (also includes author_one's blog)
    assert_equal 1, author_two.reload.all_blogs_with_subject.size

    # Expected 3, Actual 4 (also includes author_two's blog)
    assert_equal 3, author_one.reload.all_blogs_with_subject.uniq.size
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess rails has a hard time joining all those tables together. That's why you are getting wrong results.

Basically you are doing the following: Author -> Blog -> Subject -> Blog

You don't need to go back to Blog actually if you just join the subject with blog:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :author

  scope :with_subject, -> { joins(:subject) }
end

class HasManyThroughLoadTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_loading_associations_via_has_many_through
    author_one = Author.create!
    author_two = Author.create!
    Subject.create!(blogs: [Blog.new(author: author_one), Blog.new(author: author_one)])
    Subject.create!(blogs: [Blog.new(author: author_one), Blog.new(author: author_two)])

    # Expected 1, Actual 2 (also includes author_one's blog) 
    assert_equal 1, author_two.reload.blogs.with_subject.size

    # Expected 3, Actual 4 (also includes author_two's blog)
    assert_equal 3, author_one.reload.blogs.with_subject.uniq.size
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup, the last assertion should be 3 not 2. Updated the question.